# I am trying to get text area value which is in json format and passing it to jquery validation function

Tags: jquery, html, json, validation

I rendered a json-file in textarea ,which has rules and according same validation is getting done but the issue is ,I want changed text area value should get used as rules .

This  is the function through which I am rendering TEXT AREA value and I am trying to pass changed value in validate-function,but validation is not getting done as per the changes in json .

```
function getTextArea(ruleJson) {

    $("#jsonFile").text(JSON.stringify(ruleJson));

    $('#jsonFile').change(function () {
        var ruleJson = $('textarea#jsonFile').val();
        //ruleJson = JSON.parse(ruleJson);


       $.getJSON("ruleJson", function (ruleResponse) {
            ruleJson = ruleResponse;
            console.log("text area CHANGE ============"+ruleJson);  
            validateForm(ruleJson, errorJson);
        });


        //validateForm(ruleJson, errorJson);
       //console.log("text area CHANGE ============"+ruleJson);  
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the returned json in your console.log? What does `validateForm()`  look like?

Comment: currently it is giving error like -net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE but if i dont use getJSON() function ...textarea value is coming in proper json format ..validate()      function validateForm(ruleJson, errorJson) {
    $("#userForm").validate({
        rules: ruleJson,
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            $.each(errorList, function (key, value) {

Comment: Why do you have $.getJSON on the first place. All it does is make an ajax call to `/ruleJson`. You probably don't have anything there. Then you overwrite the ruleJson variable with the response which is empty. So it all makes sense. You don't need `$.getJSON`

Comment: I tried function below as             function getTextArea(ruleJson) {
        $("#jsonFile").text(JSON.stringify(ruleJson));
$('#jsonFile').change(function () {
            var ruleJson = $('textarea#jsonFile').val();
            //ruleJson = JSON.parse(ruleJson);
            validateForm(ruleJson, errorJson);
            //console.log("text area CHANGE ============"+ruleJson);  
        });}          still its not passing changed text area value rulejson into validateForm function() ......

Comment: Update your question with the `validateForm()` function and a sample JSON from the textarea.

Comment: function validateForm(ruleJson, errorJson) {
            //alert("validate form json === " + ruleJson);
            $("#userForm").validate({
                rules: ruleJson,
                showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
                    $.each(errorList, function (key, value) {
                        var errorMsg = errorJson[langCode][value.element.id][value.method];
                        
                        $("#" + value.element.id + "Error").html(errorMsg);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

Comment: SAMPLE JSON IN TEXT AREA               {"firstName":{"required":true,"noSpace":true,"lettersonly":true,"minlength":3,"maxlength":20},"lastName":{"required":true,"noSpace":true,"lettersonly":true,"minlength":5,"maxlength":30},"fullName":{"required":true,"lettersonly":true,"minlength":5,"maxlength":35,"isValidFullName":true},"loginName":{"required":true,"noSpace":true,"minlength":4,"maxlength":20},"userName":{"required":true,"minlength":4,"maxlength":20},"password":